# How to get path of file using System Specific separator from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Option `Copy Qualified Name` in Eclipse

give me  the complete file name in this way

```
/ProjecName/src/packageName/fileName
```

Now when Use this path any where in my windows it require `\` instead of `/` as separator

How can I get the file name

```
\ProjecName\src\packageName\fileName
```

This way

Because every time I have to replace this manually again with a text editor. Is there a setting or direct way to gain what I want.

Comment: windows explorer and command line will also be able to deal with slashes in many cases. Which cases do you have problems with?

Comment: ex. i want to create file with this exact path in another drive using cmd `md \ProjecName\src\packageName\`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not quite as comfortable as the copy qualified name option, but:

- open the [Properties View](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcpropview.htm)
- select the file (or other element) you want to copy the path for
- copy the value of the `location` property value in the Properties View

Unfortunately the context menu option Copy for the Properties View will also copy the property name so that the result is the concatenation of name and value.

Comment: yah not as comfortable as the copy qualified name. but  an working way and still better that manual replacing the separator, Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
String workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");      
String absoluteFilePath = "";
absoluteFilePath = workingDirectory + File.separator + filename;

System.out.println("Final filepath : " + absoluteFilePath);
```

Comment: I know this will print the path in console if i ran the code. But i need that path  to copy in clipboard without running any code, just like "Copy Qualified Name" so that i can use this path directly in somewhere else.